# Nvidia CUVID video hardware acceleration

Tags: graphics-card, video-encoding

I have Nvidia Quadro NVS 140M GPU (G86) in my laptop.

Last time when I was installing video codec pack I could turn on Nvidia CUVID hardware video decoder features at some point of configuration.

I choosen "no", because I don't know much about video formats, I have no idea about CUVID, I don't want to turn on things I don't understand.

**Can I take advantage - like save energy on battery - with CUVID?**

I can't find anywhere if this card can support CUVID or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that CUVID is available on my graphics card.

LAV video decoder configuration has hardware video accleration configuration.

In my case:

```
- Intel QuickSync mode is not available
- DXVA-copy-back  mode is available but crashes my video player
- DXVA-native     mode is available and looks like it works
- Nvidia Cuvid    mode is available and looks like it works
```

I also did few simple CPU load tests on diffrent hardware acceleration settings CUVID vs DXVA vs none.

I throttled my laptop CPU to minimum (at full speed I have 1% CPU usage) and took 4 avi files.

In 2 cases - I had 5% CPU load with CUVID, 7-10% with DXVA-native and 25% with "none".

In 2 cases - no noticeable difference between diffrent settings

So, I guess it works!